# Titanium Text-to-Speech

Tags: titanium, text-to-speech

I'm using [~Link~](https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Utterance/tree/master/android) to create a text to speech function for android in Titanium but I got some problem in development.

The module supported TTS and STT, STT function is fine but the other is not working.

I follow the documentation to create a controllers like this:

var utterance = require('bencoding.utterance'),
    speech = utterance.createSpeech();

```
if(speech.isSpeaking){
        Ti.API.info("already speaking");
    }

    speech.startSpeaking({
        text:"こんにちは"
    });
```

When I run the program. Console will show:

```
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: (main) [1191,10337] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.NullPointerException; Titanium 3.3.0,2014/07/11 12:36,787cd39
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at bencoding.utterance.SpeechProxy.onInit(SpeechProxy.java:72)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.dispatchOnInit(TextToSpeech.java:640)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.access$1000(TextToSpeech.java:52)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection.onServiceConnected(TextToSpeech.java:1296)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1187)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1204)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

even I copy the code from example.

Is it my problem? Module is added into the program.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compile that module with Titanium 3.3.0GA and works [the example](https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Utterance/blob/master/android/documentation/tts.md). What version do you use?

It is importante use this code for test device:

```
win.addEventListener('open', function()
{
    if(!utterance.isSupported())
    {
       alert("Device not compatible");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I find that the module is run normally but can't speak japanese(The example text), if I change it to number or english will work.